# F# type option problems

Tags: types, f#, option-type

i have the following code:

```
let rec sums1 n = function
            | (a,b,x:int array,s,k) when (s<n&&b=x.Length-1) -> []//None
            | (a,b,x:int array,s,k) when (a=b&&((x.Length-1)=b))->[]// None 
            | (a,b,x,s,k) when (s=n) -> (Array.toList(Array.sub x a k)) 
            | (a,b,x,s,k) when (s<n) -> sums1 n (a,b+1,x,s+x.[b+1],k+1)
            | (a,b,x,s,k) when (s>n) -> sums1 n (a+1,b,x,s-x.[a],k-1)    
            | (a,b,c,d,e) -> []//None

let neco n s =match (sums1 n (0,-1,s,0,0)) with
        | [] ->None
        | x ->Some x
let ssum n xs:list<int> = neco n (List.toArray xs)
```

How it is possible that the compiler doesn't allow me to return from ssum value of type `option< list < int > >`. I will return this type, not something else.
Have someone any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're just missing parens:

```
let ssum n (xs:list<int>) = neco n (List.toArray xs) 
           ^            ^
```

Without them, you're describing the return type of `ssum`, not the argument type of `xs`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just let type inference do it's job and remove the type declaration:

```
 let ssum n xs = neco n (List.toArray xs)
```